# How to properly define a space for correlation matrices?

Tags: matrices, statistics, random-variables, covariance, correlation

One usually defines the space
$$\{M\in\mathrm{Mat}_n(\mathbb R):\forall j, m_{jj}=1,M^\top=M\ge0\}$$
to be the space of correlation matrices. It is clear that every correlation matrix is inside this space. But how to show that for each $M$ in this space it associates with a random vector $X$ whose correlation matrix is exactly $M$, i.e. how to construct such $X$?

Comment: actually a correlation matrix is positive-semidefinite

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not think you can take any random vector X, but if X is i.i.d. standard normal then a common numerical technique to obtain correlated standard normals is to multiply the matrix $\mathbf u$ of samples from X by the [Cholesky decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition#Monte_Carlo_simulation) of M

I believe as the sample size $n\to\infty$ the resulting correlation matrix converges to M

Comment: Thanks. Based on your answer I found https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/446093/generate-correlated-normal-random-variables

Comment: Actually I think that chol(M)*X will have exact correlation matrix M (no need to use samples)