# Generating non-normal correlated random variables with Cholesky decomposition

Tags: correlation, distribution-tails, cholesky-decomposition

The Cholesky decomposition of the correlation matrix, $C$, can be used to [generate correlated random variables](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/446093/generate-correlated-normal-random-variables/446098#446098), $Y=LX$, from uncorrelated variables $X$, if $LL^{T}=C$, and if (for two correlated random variables as an example) $L$ is:

$L = \left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}c}
   1 & 0  \\
   \rho  & {\sqrt {1 - \rho ^2 } }  \\
\end{array}} \right]
$

For the above to work, the initially uncorrelated variables are required to be **standard normal** with a variance of 1, they say.

Can it be generalized though to other **non-normal distributions**, i.e. start with *non-normal* uncorrelated t-, Cauchy  or Johnson SU random variables and follow through with the same transformations to output *correlated* non-normal variables?

Answer (score 1):

I read somewhere (and I was currently trying to find the source as I found this question) that the standard normal distribution is used in generating correlated data because it maintains its normal-distributed form.

As for other distributions, by the time you use a Cholesky decomposition the generated correlated data not necessarily obey said PDF anymore. The source I'm searching actually talks about the effects of it on a Gamma distribution. Nevertheless, if you generate uncorrelated values with non-normal distributions, you'll still be able to generate correlated data, except it will not respect the same function afterwards.