# Is there a general method for generating correlated random variables from independent random variables?

Tags: random-variables, correlation

For generating correlated *normal* random variables from independent normals, I know that you can use Cholesky/SVD.

Is there a general method that applies for other random variables, e.g., uniformly distributed ones?

The above is a bit vague, so for discussion purposes, let's constrain this a bit more. How about, for each pair of the dependent random variables, we want to achieve a predefined correlation coefficient.

Comment: What is your goal? If you take $X$ and $Y=X$ they are clearly correlated. Generally, if you take any two functions from independent variables $F_1(X,Y)$ and $F_2(X,Y)$, $F_1$ and $F_2$ are likely to be correlated except for some rare cases.

Comment: @VasilyMitch I edited the OP to constrain the problem a bit more. How about we want to generate a set of correlated random variables that adhere to a prescribed correlation matrix.

Comment: [Possible dupe](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3832942/105986)

Answer (score 1):

In general, generating distributions with given properties is a hard problem. However, if you aim to creat a uniform distribution with a given correlation matrix, you can use [Gaussian Copula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copula_(probability_theory)#Gaussian_copula) for that.

In particular, given $u_i\sim U_{[0,1]}$ independently, construct $x_i=\Phi^{-1}(u_i)$, transform $y_i = R^{1/2}_{ij}x_j$, where $R_{ij}$ is a desirable correlation matrix, and finally have $v_i=\Phi(y_i)$. Variables $v_i$ are uniformly distributed with correlation matrix $R$ (since homomorphism of each of the variable doesn't change the correlation).